# 2 Different Servers - sub domain redirect url masking

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-masking

I have gone through a lot of posts about .htaccess but its not working as my websites are on 2 different servers.

I have 2 websites, both are on different servers. One is on Linux Server and the other is on Windows Server.

My main website is hosted on the linux server. Lets call this abc.com
My other website is hosted on windows server - lets call this as xyz.com

I have created a sub domain on abc.com, subdomain.abc.com

I want to redirect subdomain.abc.com to xyz.com without changing the url which should remain as subdomain.abc.com. I have tried all sorts of combination in .htaccess but it does not work. Can you please help.

Thanks
VJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IFrame instead of trying to do this with htaccess files/code.
[Using htaccess to redirect the page but keep the URL structure and change the domain only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337485/using-htaccess-to-redirect-the-page-but-keep-the-url-structure-and-change-the-do/36337643#36337643)

Edit|Update: Use iframes and not frameset. See this w3schools tutorial page. Adding an iframe is very simple so keep everything very simple - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Hi, i have done that but it does not load anything. I checked and noticed that frameset is not allowed in HTML 5, so i made some changes. Here is my code , please let me know what am i doing wrong.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html>
<head><title>MemoryCloud </title></head>


<frameset cols="100%">
<frame src="http://www.w3schools.com">
</frameset> 

</html>

Comment: @user6144832 - I have updated my answer to include a link to a simple w3schools tutorial for adding iframes.